# View não mostra valor string no campo da chave primaria

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Boas pessoal. Estou tentando listar os atributos da minha tabela no Laravel 5.6 através de uma view listar, mas no campo matrícula (PK) os valores contidos não são apresentados completamente. Esse campo é um código e é  do tipo string mas na view ele mostra somente valores positivos.

Do jeito que está abaixo, mostra assim: 0 (mas seu verdadeiro valor é 00LDA922)

**tabela imovel**

```
   public function up() {
    Schema::create('imoveis', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('matricula')->primary();
        $table->string('tipo_imovel');
        $table->float('area')->unsigned();
        $table->float('limites')->unsigned();
        $table->float('longitude');
        $table->float('latitude');
        $table->float('valor_patrimonial',9,2)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Imovel extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'imoveis';

    protected $primaryKey = 'matricula';

    protected $fillable = [
        'matricula',
        'tipo_imovel',
        'area',
        'limites',
        'longitude',
        'latitude',
        'valor_patrimonial',
        'administracao_distrital_id',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        //
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function proprietarioSingular()
    {
        //
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProprietarioSingular::class);
    }

    public function administracaoDistrital()
    {
        //
        return $this->belongsTo(AdministracaoDistrital::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function listar()
{
    $total_imoveis = $this->imovel->count();

    $total_proprietarios_s = ProprietarioSingular::count();

    $imoveis = $this->imovel->latest()->paginate(6);

    return view('painel.imovel.listar', compact('imoveis', 'total_imoveis', 'total_proprietarios_s'));
}
```

**dd($imoveis)**

```
    LengthAwarePaginator {#338 ▼
       #total: 9
       #lastPage: 2
       #items: Collection {#344 ▼
          #items: array:6 [▼
            0 => Imovel {#345 ▼
               #table: "imoveis"
               #primaryKey: "matricula"
               #fillable: array:15 [▶]
               #connection: "mysql"
               #keyType: "int"
               +incrementing: true
               #with: []
               #withCount: []
               #perPage: 15
               +exists: true
               +wasRecentlyCreated: false
               #attributes: array:17 [▼
                  "matricula" => "LD047214033"
                  "tipo_imovel" => "Residencial"
                  "area" => 44.0
                  "limites" => 45.0
                  "longitude" => 65.0
                  "latitude" => 77.0
                  "valor_patrimonial" => 45000.0
                  "created_at" => "2018-03-29 18:00:49"
                  "updated_at" => "2018-03-29 18:00:49"
               ]
               #original: array:17 [▶]
               #changes: []
               #casts: []
               #dates: []
               #dateFormat: null
               #appends: []
               #dispatchesEvents: []
               #observables: []
               #relations: []
               #touches: []
               +timestamps: true
               #hidden: []
               #visible: []
               #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            }
            1 => Imovel {#346 ▶}
            2 => Imovel {#347 ▶}
            3 => Imovel {#348 ▶}
            4 => Imovel {#349 ▶}
            5 => Imovel {#350 ▶}
          ]
       }
       #perPage: 6
       #currentPage: 1
       #path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/painel/imovel/listar"
       #query: []
       #fragment: null
       #pageName: "page"
    }
```

**view**

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

    @section('title', 'Listar imóvel')

    @section('content_header')
        <h1>
            Listar
            <small>Imóveis</small>
        </h1>

        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="active">Imóvel</li>
        </ol>
    @stop

    @section('content')
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <a href="{{route('painel.imovel.novo')}}" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Novo imóvel
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">

            @if($message = Session::get('success'))
                <!-- /.alert-dismissible-operação -->
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Alerta!</h4>
                        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
                    </div>
                @endif

                <div class="small-box bg-aqua-active">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>{{ $total_imoveis }}</h3>

                        <p>Imóveis Registratados</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="ion ion-home"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">
                        Listar todos <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>

                <h3 class="box-title">Lista de imóveis</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <!-- /.listar imovel -->
            @forelse($imoveis as $imovel)
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="box box-default box-solid">
                            <div class="box-header with-border">
                                <h3 class="box-title">Imóvel</h3>

                                <!-- /.controlo-de-permissão -->

                                <div class="pull-right box-tools">
                                    <a href="{{ url("painel/imovel/editar/$imovel->matricula") }}"
                                       class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                        <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i> Editar
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="{{ url("painel/imovel/excluir/$imovel->matricula") }}"
                                       class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Eliminar
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                                    <dt>Matrícula</dt>
                                    <!-- var_dump($imovel->matricula) -->
                                    <dd>{{ $imovel->matricula }}</dd>
                                    <dt>Tipo</dt>
                                    <dd>{{ $imovel->tipo_imovel }}</dd>
                                    <dt>Área</dt>
                                    <dd>{{ $imovel->area }}</dd>
                                    <dt>Localização</dt>
                                    <dd>{{ $imovel->provincia }}</dd>
                                    <dd>{{ $imovel->municipio }}</dd>
                                    <dt>Valor patrimonial</dt>
                                    <dd>{{ number_format($imovel->valor_patrimonial,2,',','.') }}</dd>
                                </dl>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.box-body -->
                            <div class="box-footer">
                                <a href="{{ url("painel/imovel/$imovel->matricula/proprietario-singular") }}"
                                   class="pull-left">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Proprietário
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="uppercase pull-right">Mais detalhes</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @empty
                    <p class="alert-warning">Nenhum imóvel cadastrado!</p>
                @endforelse
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
    @stop
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Manda o dd da variavel imoveis do methodo listar

Comment: Por incrível que paraça ele pega correto mas nao mostra corretamente.

Comment: O resultado final da tela você pode mandar?

Comment: Como faço isso? Mando o código msmo ou um prt screen?? Desculpa minha ignorância, sou novo na comunidade e nao sei como faço

Comment: O Codigo do HTML com o for, e o print da tela mesmo do seu problema, e quando as suas perguntas fica tranquilo, com o tempo você vai entender como é mais rapido resolver quando se tem a visão geral do problema

Comment: Beleza. Como vês nos valores q contém letras ele mostra 0, qndo passo somente números mostra correctamente

Comment: Diumanuel coloque o seu model?

Comment: Simplesmente não consigo identificar o que me está escapar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguinte, o [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) funciona assim: a *chave primária* na convenção padrão é um número auto incremento por isso na hora de mostrar o resultado o campo é submetido a um conversão para inteiro, mas, como o campo é um texto não vai funcionar e por isso do retorno ser um `0`.

> ***Porque isso acontece?***

Seu `model` está faltando configurar a *chave primária* para aceitar o dado no formato texto e não fazer a conversão para número, existem duas coisas a serem feitas no `model`:

Setar o *auto incremento* como `false`:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

isso garante que o dado não seja incrementado e que pode ser feito a sua maneira com outros tipos (`string`, `int`, etc) e também um [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) para `string` que é o fator do seu `model`:

```
protected $casts = ['matricula' => 'string'];
```

em resumo geral o seu `model` dever ser parecido assim:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Resume extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'resume';
    protected $primaryKey = 'matricula';
    protected $fillable = ['matricula', 'name' ];

    public $incrementing = false; // auto incremento desabilitado
    protected $casts = ['matricula' => 'string']; // cast
}
```

ou seja, o `model` precisa ser configurado para não ter o comportamento (convenção) padrão e seguir o comportamento que fez na sua tabela.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent)
- [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

Comment: Realmente, testei esta definição e resolveu o meu problema! Obrigado pela sua explicação caro Virgilio. Fez todo sentido agora!

Comment: Inclusive resolveu outro probleminha que dizia que estava tentando acessar um objecto desconhecido ou nulo quando houvesse um proprietário associado a um imóvel. Valeu Virgilio e Mauricio pela ajuda!!